# Predicting time-series Y (t+1) with Neural Networks in Matlab

Tags: matlab, neural-network, time-series, forecasting, autoregressive-models

I have a data set that I split into:

- **training**: predictors X_TR (1028records in 14 variables) and Y_TR (1028records single variable)
- **application**: X_APP (115 x 14), Y_APP (115x1),

where each record is a time step t.

My goal is to construct a NN model that predicts Y(t+1) using whatever historical information up to t, that is **Y(T+1) = f(X(t),X(t-1),...,Y(0),X(t),X(t-1),...,Y(0))**. Note that it is reasonable to consider iformation no older than 10 time steps. 
According to mathworks.com/help/nnet/gs/neural-network-time-series-prediction-and-modeling.html, I have trained a NN using X_T and Y_T.

```
% Cell arrays inputs for NN
X = tonndata(X_TR,false,false);
T = tonndata(Y_TR,false,false); %output volumes

% training function
trainFcn = 'trainlm';  % Levenberg-Marquardt

% Create NARX
% network parameters
lags = 10;
inputDelays = 1:lags;
feedbackDelays = 1:lags;
hiddenLayerSize = 40;
% construct  NARX net
net = narxnet(inputDelays,feedbackDelays,hiddenLayerSize,'open',trainFcn);

%prepare time series
[x,xi,ai,t] = preparets(net,X,{},T);

% Training, Validation, Testing
net.divideParam.trainRatio = 60/100;
net.divideParam.valRatio = 20/100;
net.divideParam.testRatio = 20/100;

% Train the Network
[net,tr] = train(net,x,t,xi,ai);
```

I don't know how to apply the trained model. Let say that the training was successful and I would like to apply the model on the other part of the data X_APP and Y_APP such that it predicts Y_APP(t+1). How could I do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the trained net with this instructions:

```
% define your new input
X = tonndata(X_APP, false, false);
T = tonndata(Y_APP, false, false);

% prepare new data for usage with your net
[x,xi,ai,t] = preparets(net,X,{},T);

% generate output
y = network(x,xi,ai);
```

You could also save your net and load it back to matlab at anytime:

```
 goodworkingnet = net;
 save goodworkingnet
```